# How can I set site.com/node/1 into site.com (clean)?

Tags: uri

I am trying to get my site as site.com and when I type the URL, I get site.com/node/1.

How can I get this done? If you can specify step by step, highly appreciated.

AB

Comment: Which drupal version are you using?

Comment: Do you mean front page?

Answer (score 1):

I think @JimmyKo and @Gulok, misunderstood the question OR **I myself misunderstood the question**(*If so comment me I will delete the answer*).

As stated in the question,

> I am trying to get my site as site.com and when I type the URL, I get
>   site.com/node/1.

The issue is user want site.com as his Front-Page but when he types site.com he is redirected to site.com/node/1.

If this is the case. You need to set your home page. Now to set the home page, you need to go `Configuration/Site information` for D7 and `Configuration/Basic site setting` for D8, there you set the front page path as shown in following images.

For D7 case,

> [image]

For D8 case,

> [image]

---

**Now Reverse Case,** In case I misunderstood the question

If you want to make your front page to some node like node/1, Go the same path as mentioned above and put your path there as shown in follwoign image. NOTE: There is a difference between D7 and D8 path which is `'/'`, you can see in following images.

For D7 case,

> [image]

For D8 case,

> [image]

---

**Other case(Less likely):** Have downloaded other Font-page creating module or are you using panel which provides the option of making any panel a front-page. If that is the case, those modules are overriding this default setting, Hence you have to modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking for the way to set front page.

You can visit **admin/config/system/site-information** to input `/node/1`.

It works on both Drupal 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jimmy Ko answer. It seems that your clean URL is turned off. You should enable that to have a nice URL.

To answer your original question.

[image]

What you need is to put the path there which is `node/1`. Additionaly if you have Drush installed you can set the frontpage path by running `drush vset site_frontpage PATH`.

Example:

```
drush vset site_frontpage node/1
```

To enable clean URL.

[image]

To enable clean url using Drush.

```
drush vset clean_url 1
```

NOTE: Clean URL needs to have `rewrite` (in Apache) module enabled.